# What's the music genre called - Assassin's Creed Agnus Dei

Tags: similar-artists, identify-this-genre

Can someone tell me what's the genre of the music played in `Assassin's Creed - Agnus Dei` soundtrack?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMqv_wPCKXw

I'm especially interested in the opening part, till about 0:50. How would you go about searching for similar music?

It gives me a real chill every time I listen to at and thought about listening to more similar songs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's a modern take on Plainchant / Gregorian chant: solo voice, modal harmonies, long melody lines.  If you're looking for similar, you can either go for the original - something like [this traditional 'Agnus Dei'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ETFI2U9RA&t=477s), or a modern recreation, something like this :  [Michael John Poirier - Album: Stone by Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8d4Lq97eAc).  Because this style is "different" and evocative, it is often the inspiration for soundtracks, for example this : [Halo Music Gregorian Chants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIqNWrNnQZs). But I think your keywords for searching are "plainchant" or "Gregorian chant" - with or without "soundtrack".

Comment: A commenter in the video link the OP had posted equated the melody over "miserere" with the opening of the second movement of Beethoven's 7th symphony. After listening to both, it sounds to me like an influence, though not directly taken from.